# Constructing a PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I think that PIVOT will help me accomplish this, but I can't get anything started.  I am having serious SQL brain farts today, I need some help.

Here is the output I have now:

```
Id    Name  Question    Answer
0     Test  Vault       A
0     Test  Container   1
1     Foo   Vault       B
1     Foo   Container   2
```

And this is my desired output:

```
Id   Name Vault Container
0    Test A    1
1    Foo  B    2
```

Can this be done?

If that is impossible or terribly complex to do, I have an alternate way to approach this.  The output for my alternate query is:

```
Id   Name VaultId ContainerId
0    Test A       NULL
0    Test NULL       1
1    Foo  B       NULL  
1    Foo  NULL       2
```

And here I need to be able to suppress it into one row per Id/Name.  I can't remember how to do either of these!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
     Id      INT 
    ,[Name]VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,Question       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Answer VARCHAR(10)

);  
INSERT  @Test   VALUES (0,'test1', 'vault','a');
INSERT  @Test   VALUES (0,'test1', 'Container ','1');
INSERT  @Test   VALUES (1,'test4', 'vault','b');
INSERT  @Test   VALUES (1,'test4', 'Container','2');



;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  t.id, t.[Name], t.[Question    ]   ,t.Answer
     FROM    @Test t
)

SELECT  * 
FROM    CTE
 PIVOT   ( max(answer) FOR Question     IN (vault,container) )  f;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I have got it working :)  I am going to practice with `PIVOT` what a powerful thing!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah `PIVOT` is what you need here :). Assuming your table is called `MyPivot` Try:

```
SELECT Id, Name, [Vault], [Container]
FROM (SELECT Id, Name, Question, Answer FROM MyPivot) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (MAX(Answer) FOR Question in (Vault, Container)) as p;
```

**EDIT: To demonstrate what that syntax means, see the following breakdown:**

```
PIVOT (<aggregate function>(<column being aggregated>) 
FOR <column that contains the values that will become column headers>
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column])
```

Comment: I do not understand this part: `MAX(Answer) FOR Question in (Vault, Container)`

Comment: @JoshStodola that's what you're actually pivoting, the `PIVOT` syntax is. I've edited my answer to provide a syntax breakdown for `PIVOT` for better understanding :)

Comment: what's the point of aggregating by a value if you don't show its value

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a Static Pivot:

```
create table temp
(
    id int,
    name varchar(10),
    question varchar(10),
    answer  varchar(10)
)

INSERT into temp   VALUES (0,'test', 'vault','a');
INSERT into temp   VALUES (0,'test', 'Container','1');
INSERT into temp   VALUES (1,'foo', 'vault','b');
INSERT into temp   VALUES (1,'foo', 'Container','2');

select *
from 
(
    select id, name, question, answer
    from temp
) x
pivot 
(
    max(answer)
    for question in ([container], [vault])
) p

drop table temp
```

or a dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.question) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select id, name, question, answer
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(answer)
                for question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

both will give you the same results:

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for the help!  Interesting to see the dynamic approach as well.